# Can't enter mount namespace created by a setuid process

Tags: linux, setuid, linux-namespaces

A root-owned setuid bit daemon switches back to the real user and creates a mount namespace.

A user-owned executable with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` bits set tries to enter that namespace and fails.

`daemon.c`:

```c
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1, 0, 0, 0) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  setuid(getuid()) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);
  setgid(getgid()) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  cap_t cap = cap_init();
  cap || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);
  cap_value_t cap_values[] = {CAP_SYS_ADMIN};
  cap_set_flag(cap, CAP_EFFECTIVE, sizeof(cap_values) / sizeof(cap_values[0]), cap_values, CAP_SET) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);
  cap_set_flag(cap, CAP_PERMITTED, sizeof(cap_values) / sizeof(cap_values[0]), cap_values, CAP_SET) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);
  cap_set_proc(cap) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);
  cap_free(cap) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  pause();

  return 0;
}
```

`client.c`:

```c
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  argc == 2 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  const int fd = syscall(SYS_pidfd_open, atoi(argv[1]), 0);
  fd != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  setns(fd, CLONE_NEWNS) != -1 || (perror(0), exit(1), 0);

  return 0;
}
```

`build-run.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gcc -o daemon{,.c} -lcap
gcc -o client{,.c} -lcap

sudo chown root:root ./daemon; sudo chmod u+s ./daemon
sudo setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_chroot+ep ./client

./daemon &
./client $!
```

Gives "Operation not permitted" - the `setns()` call fails. It has the correct capabilities, user namespace is the same. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace=ep ./client
```

It looks like this detail of requiring the `cap_sys_ptrace` capability is buried in the [kernel patch](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2020-January/041109.html) in a code comment:

```
+ * This syscall gets a copy of a file descriptor from another process
+ * based on the pidfd, and file descriptor number. It requires that
+ * the calling process has the ability to ptrace the process represented
+ * by the pidfd. The process which is having its file descriptor copied
+ * is otherwise unaffected.
```